# How to animate particles to collide with geometry but stay within the boundaries of the path they follow?

Tags: animation, particles, keyframes

I am trying to make an animation of blood flow being pinched off and stopping at the point of the compression within an artery.

Here is a link to a video of what I have so far... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvVitERwL5g

As of right now I have a sphere emitting particles that follow a curve guide that is placed along the interior of my artery model.

What I want is something like this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2vZtPXV7A0

As you can see in the second video, the blood cells collect at the valve and then once it is opened, they continue along their path. I would like to have this same effect with my animation of the compressed artery. I want the particles to stop there flow at the compression and resume their flow once the compression loosens, all while staying within the boundaries of the interior artery.

Can anyone tell me how to go about this? Thanks dudes :)